# How to set role in Apache IoTDB to have permission to manage all time series?

Tags: roles, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now learning the permission settings of Apache IoTDB and I know that IoTDB can set user role to manage different time series. I wonder can IoTDB create a user with permissions of all time series rather than one time series? If IoTDB can do that, how can I set this role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions can be granted to `root.**`, which means to all time series in Apache IoTDB. You can write your statement like: `GRANT USER <userName> PRIVILEGES <privileges> ON on root.**`.